# Add new elements to a javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I'm trying to do a page with HTML and JQuery. What I want to do with this is typing an e-mail in a textbox and when a button is pressed, add him to an object, and show the new e-mail added and the ones already sent. My problem is that the new e-mail replace the one I had, It's not added after it. How can I solve it?

Here's my code

```
enter code here

<html>
<head>
    <script src="config/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var obj = {};

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#agr').click(function(){
                var correo_val = $('#correoe').val();
                var estrc = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

                if(correo_val == ''){
                    alert("Debes agregar un correo");
                }
                else if(!estrc.test(correo_val)){
                    alert("Correo no valido");
                }
                else if(estrc.test(correo_val)){
                    alert("Correo agregado exitosamente");
                    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(correo_val)){
                        arr = [];
                        arr.push(correo_val);
                        // obj=arr;
                        obj2 = {};
                        obj2 = arr;
                        obj = obj2;

                    }else{  

                        obj2 = {};
                        obj = obj2;
                    }

                    alert(obj);
                    $("#listac").html(obj);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table style='margin-top:10%' align='center'>
            <tr> <td> Ingresar correo electr&oacutenico                    </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> <input type='text' name='correoe' id='correoe'>                  </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> <input type='button' name='agregar' value='agregar' id='agr'> </td> </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div style="background:#FFFFFF;border:0" class="box" id="LCriterios">
        <h1><span id="field"></span><span style="float:right;"></span></h1>
        <!--<label><span>Tipo de operaci&oacuten</b></span><select class='opSelect' name='selOp' id='selOp'></select></label>
        <label id='selCriterio'></label>
        <label style="height: 30px;"><input type="button" class="btAgregar" value="Agregar" id="btn_add"/></label>-->
        <label id="label12">Correos electr&oacutenicos </label>
        <div id='listac'></div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6xxovyv/) with one adjustment of your javascript -

```
if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(correo_val)){
                    arr = []; //  <-- move this to the first line where
                              // you already have var obj = {};
                    arr.push(correo_val);
                    ...
```

Move the `arr = [];` that you use to store the valid emails from this `if()` clause to the first line of your code where you also declared `var obj = {};`. Otherwise `arr = [];` will be an empty array every time before you add another email and always have only one element (the last email that was added).